# Show that it is impossible to order C (complex numbers) so that it becomes an ordered field.

Tags: complex-numbers

Hint: Assume (C, +, *, <) is an ordered field for some order relation <. Then consider i is not equal to 0. One has either i>0 or i<0. In either case, find a contradiction.

Comment: Yes, go ahead. You are almost there.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** what happens when you multiply both sides of the inequality by $i$?

---

**Clarification:**

To begin, suppose that $i>0$. Then since $i>0$, we can multiply both sides of the inequality by $i$ to get $i^2 >0$ (the inequality doesn't flip because $i>0$).  Why is this a contradiction?

Now, what happens when we assume $i<0$?

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: I've added to my answer in an attempt to make what I meant clearer. Let me know if you're still confused.

Answer (score 0):

Assume to the contrary that one can define a total ordering $>$ on $\mathbb{C}$. It is obvious that $i \neq 0$. So we need check if $i>0$ or $0>i$ are possible.

Case 1: Assume that $i>0$. By definition and our assumption, we have that

> $i\cdot i =-1> i \cdot 0 = 0$

which is impossible.

Case 2: Assume that $0>i$. Then by definition and our assumption,

> $0+(-i)=-i>i+(-i)=0$

But then we notice that

> $0\cdot (-i)=0>i\cdot(-i)=1$

which is impossible.