# Proof that no order can be defined in the complex field that turns it into an ordered field: question on proof

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, order-theory

The question at hand is stated in the title.

Typical proofs that I have read involves taking a complex number i, then reaching some contradiction with i<sup>2</sup> > 0.

I feel like these proofs bypass the problem of what it means to define an order in the complex field. In other words, what does it mean to have 1 complex number larger/smaller than the other?

Intuitively, taking the norm is the obvious way to compare, but that violates 'if x>y, y-x < 0'. Nonetheless, the cause to my confusion is there seems to be many ways that an 'order' can be defined, and until each one of them is explored, one cannot prove if a complex field can or cannot be ordered.

Keen to hear your comments on my amateurish view.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Complex numbers can be ordered, but not in a way compatible with field operations

Comment: Acknowledging J.W. Tanner's comment, the way my complex function theory book specifically defines order is that field $F$ must have a subset $P$ such that (1) $(a \in P \wedge b \in P) \Rightarrow ([a+b] \in P \wedge [a\times b] \in P).$ and (2) $0$ not in $P$ and $a \neq 0$ implies that exactly one of $[a, -a]$ are in $P$.  Without *some* definition of ordering, any *proof* becomes meaningless.  Re your instinct about linking ordering to (for example) $|z|$, don't you want ordering to provide that  $z_1 \neq z_2$ implies that they don't have the same *order*?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: Tanner: may I have a proof/reference to the statement? Or was the proof I listed the one.

user2661923: I understand that there must be a definition for ordering for a proof to function. According to your textbook's def, it seems complex numbers are ordered? (I know they are not) In mine (Rubin), order is defined with:
For 2 elements, one of x>y, x=y, x<y is true. But I don't see how 2 complex numbers can be compared. 

Thank you for the responses and I apologize in advance for the difficulty in communication due to my lack of rigorous mathematical knowledge.

Comment: With respect to proving that $\mathbb{C}$ is **not** an ordered Field, based
on the definition of an ordered Field, in my earlier comment, I will (again)
excerpt "An Introduction to Complex Function Theory" 1991 (Appendix A) - [Bruce Palka].
Suppose that $P$ is a subset of $\mathbb{C}$, with the properties re my previous comment.
Since $i \neq 0$ exactly one of $\{i, -i\}$ is in $P$.  In either case,
$(i)^2 = (-1) = (-i)^2$ must then be in $P$.  Therefore, $(-1)^2 = (1)$ is in $P$.
This is a contradiction, since $P$ can not contain both $(-1)$ and $(1)$.

Comment: It was only an accident (re my random browsing) that I saw your comment.  The following link shows how to address a comment so that the user is automatically
notified: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for clarifying I see that this proof does not involve the '<' '>' symbols, and I am more comfortable.

Comment: Using $\mathbb{R}$ as an example of an ordered field, with $\mathbb{R^+}$ serving as $P$ re the proof in one of my previous comments, you then define the relation $(a > b)$ by $\{[a > b] \iff [a + (-b) \in \mathbb{R^+}]\}$.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner " Complex numbers can be ordered, but not in a way compatible with field operations" : Is the following an example of what you have in mind.  If $z = (x + iy), w = (u + iv)$ then $\{[z > w] \iff [(x > u) \vee (x = u \wedge y > v)]\}$?

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487997/total-ordering-on-complex-numbers) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2726892/prove-that-no-order-can-be-defined-in-the-complex-field-that-turns-it-into-an-or) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130055/can-the-complex-numbers-be-totally-ordered-and-how-is-this-different-to-mathbb) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2842685/doubts-in-proof-of-complex-numbers-not-an-ordered-field) ...

Comment: and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1876259/baby-rudin-chapter-1-exercise-9-complex-field-ordering) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004998/ordered-field-proof) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181720/proof-of-non-ordering-of-complex-field) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598719/show-that-it-is-impossible-to-order-c-complex-numbers-so-that-it-becomes-an-or) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1620004/ordering-of-complex-plane)

Comment: and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498797/how-can-we-have-distance-without-order-in-complex-numbers)